# Как пройти авторизацию через GitHub api не используя Authorization callback URL

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin, oauth, github-api

Вообщем, нужно авторизировать пользователя с помощью GitHub API, не при обычной **oAuth**  нужно указывать  `Authorization callback URL` что  подразумевает, что есть еще `web-приложение` которое ловит эти `callback-и`.

У меня **ВОПРОС**: можно ли как то авторизировать пользователя?

**P.S.**я видел есть Basic Auth.. но не совсем понял - через curl  у меня запрос прошел но как сделать такое же через Retrofit не получилось.

> https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication

```
/**
 * User auth.
 *
 * Api method reference: https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#via-username-and-password
 *
 * @param userName - user name on GitHub.
 * @return GitHub user profile.
 */
@POST("user")
fun basicAuth(@Query("u") userName: String): Observable<Response<Profile>>
```

и получаю следующую ошибку

> {"message":"Bad
>   credentials","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}

Что в принципе и логично так как я туда не передаю пароль, в этом случае у меня **ВОПРОС:** как передать туда `<username>` и `<password>`

Comment: В ретрофите авторизация делается через interceptor'ы. в частности [Authentificator](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit)

Comment: Basic Auth элементарна в имплементации, прочите спецификацию если желаете. Если нет, как уже сказали, есть в Retrofit для этого interceptor-ы: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам стоит посмотреть в сторону готовой библиотеки для аутентификации по Ouath2 для github:
https://github.com/mimicmobile/okhttp-oauth2-client